# The label “Cancel” from modal segue in Apple Watch showing wrong text - "abbrechen"

Tags: ios, swift, segue, apple-watch, watchos

When my `WKInterfaceController` poped up by pressing a menuItem (which was settup by "`self.addMenuItem` in mainScreen"), the title on the poped WKInterfaceController shows "`abbrechen`" instead of "`Cancel`". Anyone know how to fix it to make it showing "`Cancel`"? Or like where did I probably make a mistake?

```
//MainScreen.swift
func setContextItems(directToEnabled: Bool) {
        self.clearAllMenuItems()
        self.addMenuItem(with: WKMenuItemIcon.decline, title: "direct", action: #selector(MainScreen.freePressed))
}
```

Clues:

- It happens only on my Apple Watch device (WatchOS 3.1). When it runs
  on the simulator(Xcode 8.2.1, iPhone 7 plus), it works fine showing
  "Cancel".
- My Langauge & Region are both English. "Langauge & Region" in my Watch App and my iPhone setting are both English for language and Australian for region.
- "abbrechen" is "abort" or "cancel" in German.
- There's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032325/how-can-i-change-the-label-cancel-from-modal-segue-in-apple-watch) on SO.
- Maybe I changed some plist setting for langauge somewhere.
- I searched my project, and I can not find keywords like "german", "abbrechen"
- I did used "#if (`TARGET_OS_IOS || TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR`)", but there's nothing related.

I guess I might change a plist somewhere that change the locale/laguage only on the Apple Watch. Or maybe it's a rare WatchOS bug. Anyone saw similar problem before ?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are overriding the language settings when installing over Xcode. This can be done using the scheme editor in Xcode:

- Click the target in the Run destination menu and choose Edit Scheme.
- On the right, select Options.
- Check `Application Language` setting

[image: scheme editor language settings]

More information on [Testing Specific Languages and Regions (@developer.apple.com)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/TestingYourInternationalApp/TestingYourInternationalApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH7-SW2)

Comment: It was "System Language" by default there, which should be English.
I changed it to English, but it doesn't work. Thanks for providing this method though, I didn't try this.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused by you code? You are giving it the title 'direct' but expecting a title of 'Cancel'?

Should you not be doing:

```
    self.clearAllMenuItems()
    self.addMenuItem(withImageNamed: "imageFileForDirectButton", title: "Direct", action: #selector(TheController.menuDirectButtonPressedFunction))
    self.addMenuItem(with: WKMenuItemIcon.decline, title: "Cancel", action: #selector(TheController.menuCancelButtonPressedFunction))
```

Comment: The title showing here is the title for the itemMenu, but what I asking the title of the poped WKInterfaceController.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding the title?

```
override func awake(withContext context: Any?)
{
    self.setTitle("Cancel")       
    super.awake(withContext: context)
}

override func willActivate()
{
    self.setTitle("Cancel")
}
```